# iOS 11.2 delivered notifications from notification centre don't remove

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest, ios11.2

I have been using `removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers:` and `removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers` methods to remove local notification from the notification centre.

It has been working perfectly until I updated my device to iOS 11.2.2, Notification remain in the notification centre. If I run `getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler`, it returns an empty array.

After executing removal command from the code, if remove one notification of the app from the tray, rest of the notifications of the same app get removed as well.

Each notification has a different identifier.

I have another device which has 11.1, notifications are being removed perfectly on this device.

Comment: I confirm what is happening to you, and the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108165/unusernotificationcenter-removealldeliverednotifications-not-working-in-ios-11-2) is talking about this.