# iOS 11 new notification center removes all delivered notifications after user make any action with one of them

Tags: notifications, ios11, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I have an issue on iOS 11. All delivered notification automatically removing from notification tray after I select any action for one of them. This happens before my code start handling action. In iOS 10 everything is ok, all delivered notifications stay in delivered and disappear only notification where I proceed some action.
My app schedule reminders with custom action, 2 buttons Activate and Stop. User can receive many of them in one day, but its very important to keep already delivered notifications, because most of them is uniq and make different actions.
If it is iOS 11 new notification center behavior or known issue, where I can read about this? Thanks a lot for help.
Minimum deployment target in my app is iOS10 and I use new UNNotificationRequest for scheduling local notifications.

Comment: I confirm what is happening to you, and the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108165/unusernotificationcenter-removealldeliverednotifications-not-working-in-ios-11-2) is talking about this.

Comment: @HarryNg I have other problem, I don't want to remove delivered notifications, they should stay in place. Main problem that they disappear before my app run any code.

Comment: @HarryNg Oh, yes, I found, thank you.